# SQL Server whole database collation change

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've searched this topic before and found this guide from another question posted:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/302405/The-Easy-way-of-changing-Collation-of-all-Database

I tried to follow through with it but ran into problems. When dropping the indexes not all were deleted because they are full text enabled. I then manually deleted the full text indexes (I didn't know how to preserve them so I have to find out how to do that as well). After that I got errors when changing the collation of all the columns for foreign key constraints.

In summary: I need to script all my indexes, full text indexes and foreign key constraints --> change collation of all columns --> re-create all indexes and foreign keys.

Can someone please direct me in the right way to do this, I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Couldn't it maybe be easier to just re-create the whole database with the proper collation, and then migrate data over? Changing the collation over a lot of tables and columns can become very cumbersome and hard to complete....

Comment: Would I still be able to migrate the data? Because the original data is in a different collation so it wouldn't be able to resolve the equal values

Comment: Try RedGate Toolbelt. I think there is a free trail version you can use. It makes the process of changing collation easy and fast

Comment: @Van I downloaded it but not sure how to proceed with changing the collation. Do you know how?